# How to avoid adding more and more states to a class?

Tags: c++

Lets say I decided to write an app which proceeded letters.
So I crafted a class which represents the concept:

```
class Letter
{
  //implementation1
};
```

Then I realized that I need to add some "flags" for letters, such as "processing", "processed", "wont_be_processed".

```
class Letter
{
  //implementation1
  state letter_state_;
};
```

And assume that all letters are stored in some container.
(I want to be clear that above-mentioned states are necessary for implementation,
and are not part of business-logic.) 
And finally I understood that I need another special flag, which will be used for only one Letter object among all, stored in the container.

So two naive ways how to proceed further which I see now are:

1) add another flag; 
2) add another field. 
Note, that the first option will be unnatural, because "processing", "processed", "wont_be_processed" somehow relate to each other, and the new state will not relate to them properly.
The second option leads to class bloat, also a colleague of mine doesn't like adding new fields (however, without proving a rationale).

Is there a set name for such design pitfall or a standard way of overcoming the problem?

Upd. Added example. 
**Was**

```
void process_letter(Letter& foo)
{
    if(foo.latter_state_ == states::wont_be_processed)
         return;

    if(foo.letter_state_ == states::processed)
        process_impl_1(foo);

}
```

**Will be?**

```
void process_letter(Letter& foo)
{
    if(foo.latter_state_ == states::wont_be_processed
       && foo.new_spacial_state_ != special_state::bar)
         return;

    if(foo.letter_state_ == states::processed)
        process_impl_1(foo);

}
```

Upd2 
Maybe, the whole design is completely wrong. If so, should I close the question?

Comment: There are only two possibilities: 1) original states do not apply when new state is in force, 2) original states are independent of new state and may still be applied.  If 1) then it is a new state.  If 2) then it is a new field.

Comment: It's the second case. However, assume that the class is rather big and I will need to add new lines of code in constructor to properly work with the new field and also I will need to change the code, responsible for serialization of the class. So adding new field will cause changes in different files. Meanwhile, the only consumer of this field will be one "if" in one method. Is there a line where I should stop adding new fields for such "properities"?

Comment: Probably, the use of word "state" is misleading. I just need to somehow assign properties to letters to process them based on this properties. However I do not want to introduce new classes for different letters and write a factory to create them. Also, I try to avoid using dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: Why not have a single variable per container that points to the special letter?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two items:

1. Enumerate the states
2. Use a state table

The idea here is to make the code so that it has least amount of changes.  Placing the state data into a table will allow you to grow the table with the least amount of changes to the executable code.

For a state table, there are many implementations.  For example, search the internet for "state design pattern c++".

A good book or reference will help you with the enumerations.

**Edit 1: State table example**
You can have table of [state-id, function-pointer]:

```
struct State_Entry
{
  unsigned int  state_id;
  void (*Ptr_State_Processing_Function)(unsigned int state_id);
};
```

A nice feature of placing the state ID into the table is that the state's don't have to be contiguous or homogeneous. Also, by keeping the function pointer's type simple, you eliminate the issue of functions having different signatures (function pointers must be of the same type/signature).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! By enumerating states you mean using enum or more general abstract enumeration? 
The problem, which I, probably, failed to properly address in my question, is that I already have one group of states and I need to add new states which is not aligned with others. I read about "state pattern", however I don't understand how it faces "non-homogeneous" states.

Comment: You can create a new list where the first enumerated value is the last value in an existing `enum`.

Comment: The most fundamental state table is a table of structures containing the state ID and a pointer to a function that processes the state.  You can get more fancy by using functors.

Comment: "In object-oriented design, objects can modify their behavior based on the current state of their attributes" (from [drdobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/state-patterns-c/184404132) ) It seems like state table is used when object changes behavior of it's own methods based on state (well, now I regret for using this word, because It looks like it was misleading.), but in my case ( I should have provided example earlier) processing happens in outer classes. Does the pattern still apply ?

Comment: Try using a state table.  It's a lot simpler than the design pattern.